# MVC 3 Deploy Automation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild, build-automation

I am looking for the most straight forward way to automate the deploy of an MVC 3 application. There is a wealth of information on Stack Overflow already, but much of it seems to be old, and I am not sure what is still relevant to MVC 3.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

- Publish MVC application
- Zip files
- Copy zip to remote location

It is the “Publish” part of this I am having the most trouble with.  Here are my main points of confusion:

- How can an automated build be initiated for an MVC 3 app?  Do we need to use the AspNetComiler MSBuild Task?  I have seen an example of this uses in conjunction with a CSC Task.  Are both really needed?
- There is a “Build Deployment Package” option in Visual Studio.  Can this be initiated with MSBuild?  Should this be used instead?
- Web Deployment Projects: where do these fit into the picture?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where are you deploying this to? A local instance of IIS? Azure? Windows Server hosted somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

I am by far not specialist in application deployment so there might be better ways but here's what I do.

- I use [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24509) to precompile my ASP.NET MVC 3 application
- I feed the result of this project to a Setup and Deployment Project
- I wrote a custom assembly which is applied to this Setup and Deplyment Project as an Install step and which based on the target IIS version creates App Pool and Virtual Directories.
- I ship an MSI to the team responsible for deploying the application. All they need to do is to schedule a task which does an `msiexec /u myapp.msi` and then `msiexec /i myapp.msi`.

Remark : in my case all builds are automated in a continuous integration fashion with a Team Foundation Server Build but if you don't have a build server you could also build it manually by running the setup and deployment project which spits an MSI.

Comment: Web Deployment Projects look interesting, thanks for the link.  That may well be the answer.  Do they need Visual Studio to run, or can they be built on a server without a VS install?  Also, I would still like to understand if the ASPNetCompiler is still relevant for MVC 3, and also to automate the creation of a Build Deployment Package.  Just trying to understand the options, so I can make an educated decision about which is right for our situation.

Comment: @James, Web Deployment Projects do not require Visual Studio to build. They only need MSBuild as they are implemented as custom MSBuild tasks.